# can't read context params from web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml

I am writing a J2EE web application with NetBeans running in Tomcat 7.0.41.  I've created a deployment descriptor, web.xml, with four context-params in it.  I've created a class that extends HttpServlet.  In the init method for the class, when I call getInitParameterNames from the ServletConfig instance, I get an empty enumeration.  Ultimately, I suspect Tomcat isn't reading the web.xml file at all because I had to resort to using the @WebServlet annotation to even reach the servlet at all.  Can anyone suggest why I can't access the context-params and/or why Tomcat isn't reading the web.xml file?

Here is the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>preptimeminutes</param-name>
    <param-value>60</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>preptimehours</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>servings</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>calories</param-name>
    <param-value>100</param-value>
</context-param>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Here is the code for the init method:

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException
{
    int preptemp;
    String tempString1, tempString2;
    Enumeration<String> e = servletConfig.getInitParameterNames();

this.servletConfig = servletConfig;
    servletContext = servletConfig.getServletContext();

    try 
    {
        while(e.hasMoreElements())
        {
           servletContext.log(e.nextElement());       
        }
    } ...
}
```

Thanks,

Jason Mazzotta

Comment: It would help to see your web.xml and a code snippet from your Servlet.

Comment: Is the web.xml deployed to the correct location?  Does it have any errors repotered at startup?

Comment: No errors are reported at startup.  The web.xml file is located in WEB-INF subdirectory of the docBase listed in context.xml.

Comment: Do `request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("preptimeminutes");` work?

Comment: No, unfortunately, that doesn't work.  That's why I switched to using getInitParameterNames; to see if I could read anything at all.

Comment: Why are you overwriting `init(ServletConfig)`? This method has predefined scenario that handles adding servlet to available servlets pool. At least add `super(servletConfig)` at start of this method or even better override `init()` with no parameters and use `getServletContext().getInitParameterNames()` to get available context parameter names. Also remember that `init` is invoked by default where servlet is requested first time, not when server starts (unless you change that).

Comment: Thanks, Pshemo.  That was the problem.  I switched the signature of the init method.  I also referred to the ServletContext instead of the ServletConfig.  At that level, I was able to read the context-params.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to read parameters of `ServletContex` (the ones for entire application), but you ended up with reading `ServletConfig` (the ones for specific servlet).

Another potential problem is that you are overriding `init(ServletConfig)` instead of `init()`. First method shouldn't be overridden because it handles many servlet life cycle tasks like adding servlet to available servlets pool. If you want to add something to initialization process you should override `init()` method which is invoked later by `init(ServletConfig)`.

So try maybe something like

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException
{
    ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
    Enumeration<String> e = servletContext.getInitParameterNames();
    try 
    {
        while(e.hasMoreElements())
        {
           servletContext.log(e.nextElement());       
        }
    } ...
}
```

Comment: ... or else call `super(config)` from `init(ServletConfig config).`

Comment: @EJP Agree, but overriding `init()` instead of `init(ServletConfig)` is better, so I decided to skip this variant in answer. I mentioned about it earlier in [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819064/cant-read-context-params-from-web-xml/21820171?noredirect=1#comment33021536_21819064) but placing it in answer would seem like encouraging others to use it which is what I try to avoid.